# PHP session variable not being set

Tags: php, session

I am aware that there are several topics about this but after hours of reading I still can't figure out what's going wrong.

I'm building a survey with a login screen at index.php. The user is required to insert their name and submit the form. The username should be saved and passed onto setup1.php.

This is part of my index.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    print session_id();
?>
<form id="login" method="POST" action="setup1.php">
<input id="participant" name="participant" type="text" size="20"/>
<input type="submit" name="start" value="Start"/>
</form>
<?php
    $name = $_POST['participant'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $name;
?>
```

Start of setup1.php:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    print session_id();
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

My $_SESSION variable is empty, I have nothing printed on the following page setup.php. I would appreciate if you could help.

Comment: use $_SESSION not %_SESSION

Comment: No need to `session_start` twice (or is this intentionally).

Comment: Sorry, this was a typo, I just changed it. I learned that I'd have to include session_start(); at the beginning of each file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `$_POST` code is in the wrong file. Your form is going to `setup1.php`, but you're trying to set the `$_SESSION` in your `index.php`.

You need to take it out of there and put it in `setup1.php`:

```
<?php
  session_start();

  if (!isset($_POST['participant'])) {
    die('No $_POST data');
  }

  $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['participant'];

  print session_id();
  print_r($_SESSION);
  echo $_SESSION['username'];
?>
```

Also, make sure that you're using `$_SESSION` and not `%_SESSION`. I hope it was just a typo.

Comment: Thanks for picking that up, @satishrajak. I'm hoping it was just a type on their end. I just copy + pasted it.

Comment: `die("No $_POST data");` - this will generate `Notice: Array to string conversion` - use single quotes not to evaluate this `$_POST` array

Comment: Was meant to put single quotes! @n-dru

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo!

Answer (score 0):

Your form hasn't been submitted when you set the `$_SESSION['username']`, i.e., `$_POST['participant']` has no value.

You should move the piece of code below from index.php to setup1.php

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['participant'];
$_SESSION['username'] = $name;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

### index.php

`<?php
session_start();
?>`

`<form id="login" method="POST" action="setup1.php">
<input id="participant" name="participant" type="text" size="20"/>
<input type="submit" name="start" value="Start"/>
</form>`

### setup1.php

`<?php
session_start();`

`if(isset($_POST['participant']) && ! empty($_POST['participant']))`
`{
      $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['participant'];
      echo $_SESSION['username'];
}`
?>`

Comment: Please don't use %_SESSION